# LLM generates `<0x0A><0x0A>` in place of newline character in LM studio

Tags: newline, large-language-model

The [mixtral7Bx2](https://huggingface.co/TheBloke/Mixtral_7Bx2_MoE-GGUF) model gives me these characters `<0x0A><0x0A>` instead of a new line on LM Studio chat. Some models also have this issue while others don't.

What is the cause of it and how to fix it?

[image]